# How to prevent logrotate from producing unwanted ".backup" files

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate

I have a logrotate config on ubuntu 16.04 which is meant to rotate my logs to gz daily. The config is like so:

```
/opt/dcm4chee/server/default/log/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 5
    compress
    notifempty
    create 0640 dcm4chee dcm4chee
    sharedscripts
    copytruncate
}
```

It produces correctly the gzipped logs:

```
server.log.1.gz
...
server.log.5.gz
```

However it also produces a bunch of unwanted "backups" rather sporadically which are causing runaway disk usage over time - we are operating on limited disk space VMs:

```
server.log.1-2018063006.backup
...
server.log.1-2018081406.backup
```

This completely defeats my original purpose of capping disk usage by rotating and compressing a finite number of logs in the first place.

How do I stop logrotate from generating these 'backups' completely? If this means losing a few lines of logging, so be it.

I am unable to find documentation on the matter. Currently I have a crontab setup which deletes these files periodically, but it doesn't seem like the 'right' way to do things.

Comment: Do you have some other logrotate settings that might match some of the same files? With a `dateext` directive or similar?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I see no other logrotate rules that match that directory (I examined each file within /etc/logrotate.d), and did a grep for dateext and no luck.

Comment: The only other place I can think of is `/etc/logrotate.conf`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. No reference to either dateext or the /opt/dcm4chee in /etc/logrotate.conf either. There is another log file in the system to which the same thing is happening. They are from separate processes. However, the one thing both of them have in common is that they are very frequently written to (a couple of lines a second) compared to the other stuff I am managing with logrotate. Not sure if that could be a cause ...

Comment: It might be something else rotating them, not sure what, though, I'm afraid. Maybe you can see something in the system logs?

Answer (score 7):

Running into same issue and found out that it's caused by duplicate log files.

In my case, I'm logrotating some nginx logs, and by using the create method, this sometimes happens, when its trying to create a new log file, somehow nginx still produces new logs and leads to below errors:

```
error: destination /[example path]/access.log already exists, renaming to /[example path]/access.log-2018122810.backup
```

and so it keep making tons of ".backup" files and consume my disk space.

After doing some research, I just couldn't find a good way to kill all nginx processes, so I temporary fix it by adding `copytruncate` inside my logrotate.d config, and it seems to solve the issue but have to take the risk of you may lost some log.

Hope there's a much more better solution~

Comment: Interesting hint -- in my case copytruncate seems not to solve the problem, I will take another look though when I have time, haven't thought about this in a while, I've instead settled for creating a cron job that deletes these files nightly when they are older than x days.

Comment: For me, this happened because I had two instances of logrotate running. One in a cron, and another in cron.d; the two would run at the same time, causing files to be locked when the second ran, creating the `.backup` files.

Comment: My problem was in line `compressoptions -9 --threads=0` for xz options. When low memory logrotate run compression with xz and exit with errors **/usr/bin/xz: (stdin): Cannot allocate memory** and leave `*.backup` file each fail run. Remove `--threads=0` for one thread mode with less memory. Modified line `compressoptions -9`.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to remove the `create` if that causes issues.

Answer (score 7):

This occurs when two instances of logrotate run concurrently on the same set of log files.

For example - This can happen when one instance is running as a part of your regular cron.d that runs daily and another instance is running as a part of your cron job

Comment: This was the case for me too. I spent days trying to work out what was going wrong and didn't realize there where two crons running. One was in `crontab -l` and the other in `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`

Comment: In my case it was a `systemd` timer for logrotate - which seems to be set up by default in Debian Buster and onwards - which clashed with my manual cronjob - check with `systemctl list-timers --all`

Comment: systemd vs cron job for me too ...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had some custom nginx logrotate configuration in `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx`.  I had a cron job in `/etc/cron.d/logrotate_nginx` that called it every 10 minutes:

```
*/10 * * * * root /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/nginx | logger -t logrotate_nginx
```

Solution was to move the nginx configuration out of `/etc/logrotate.d` and into `/usr/logrotate.d` (any other directory really) so that the system-installed logrotate doesn't execute the custom nginx logrotate configuration:

```
*/10 * * * * root /usr/sbin/logrotate /usr/logrotate.d/nginx | logger -t logrotate_nginx
```